# How to resize uploaded inline images with ckeditor in drupal 8

Tags: image, image-processing, drupal, ckeditor, drupal-8

In drupal 8, I try to resize uploaded images via ckeditor. Images are not resizing when uploaded via the ckeditor. How to resize inline-image with ckeditor in drupal 8 ?

There is an option in the "Text format" to resize "scale down" the image. But this setting does nothing ? any tips ?

[The Drupal "FULL HTML" text format settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoBnk.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think CKEDITOR could resize your images (it never could).
You could only set width and height properties yourself in "Source Code", but it will only visually resize image.

As alternative you could try install [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) drupal modules, which has this feature

Comment: This statement is not valid anymore. CKEditor can resize images.

Answer (score 9):

Druapl 8 offers drag resizing of images out of the box. If you have set up the 'Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML
Enabled' filter in your editor(setup at `/admin/config/content/formats`) , make sure that the `<img>` tag is added to it with the height and width attributes (Ex: `<img height width>`) and then you can see a black drag handle at the bottom right hand corner of the editor in your nodes.

Adding this info here so it can be useful for others looking for a solution!

Comment: This was a huge help and saved me a ton of time looking for the reason why people couldn't scale their images in the editor.  Just to note, this is not actually resizing the images, just scaling them down but still requiring visitors to download the full-sized image regardless of the dimensions it is being displayed at. If you set up your media types with a reasonable size limit on images this isn't that big of a deal but still something to keep in mind.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; holds true for a D9 site I'm setting up.